# PEM_read_bio_X509 failed when load pem or crt file

Tags: nginx, openssl, x509

i compile install nginx 1.4.4 and openssl 1.0.1h,after install i generate .pem and .key file and put them under conf directory,when i want to start it shows something was wrong.

```
nginx$ sbin/nginx
nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509("/home/work/nginx/conf/33iq.crt") failed (SSL:)
```

it only can see PEM_read_bio_X509 failed but no ssl error info,how to find out what is wrong with it?

```
openssl x509 -in /home/work/nginx/conf/33iq.crt -inform PEM -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 9271295828916739212 (0x80aa426f5a249c8c)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=UN, ST=CD, L=sodaf, O=ser, OU=fas, CN=ea/emailAddress=abc@baidu.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 14 10:12:12 2014 GMT
            Not After : Jul 14 10:12:12 2015 GMT
        Subject: C=UN, ST=CD, L=sodaf, O=ser, OU=fas, CN=ea/emailAddress=abc@163.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus:
                    ...
                    eb:ce:5a:36:ae:ca:e8:26:2d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         ...
         76:68
```

Comment: You can try to execute this command: `openssl x509 -in /home/work/nginx/conf/33iq.crt -inform PEM -text -noout`. It will  perform certificate reading and parsing and hopefully will give you more detailed error message.

Comment: @jariq,i execute the command but get no error message

Comment: Certificate seems to be OK. What about the file system permissions? Can user account under which nginx is executed access the file?

Comment: @jariq,the file system permissions is ok.only compile nginx,openssl,pcre can read the pem/key file,so i think maybe some moudle cause this problem.